# Newsletter, mailingList and contact management

Tags: contact, newsletter, mailing-list

I think it's a good question, and my research don't come to a FINAL answer, so i turn to you WordPress community. here is the question

I have about 300 email that i like to take from entourage to a catalog (contact database) WordPress seem fit to do that. After having a nice interface to get the first name, last name, telephone, email, company, etc in the database to manage contact in WordPress much like a CRM for the person on the road and in the office to get hold to that info anywhere

Then i like to get those  person in the database to get a nice mailing newsletter each month in there inbox. Use the WordPress post to get the thing together, and hit a button, the post #123 send to 300 email, and get some stat on how many have open the email and so on...

So, WordPress is a nice platform to do that, but i will need a plugin(s) to do that... and listing in the plugins database of WordPress plugin dont help me

What i need, is THE best one to do that, cheep and efficiently...

so you guys, have real world experience with that... what plusin do that ?

thanks in advance

-

i have found that comparison link, but it just add more option, and no real answer : http://winkpress.com/newsletter/subscribe/

Comment: You could just use MailChimp for the mailing part. That's free for up to 2000 emails. Alternative might be Campaign Monitor, but that's not free. Both might have wordpress plugins to help integration.

Comment: MailChimp look interesting.. but i prefer a system totally on my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Kim a dude working on Wysija, the plugin mentioned.

Yes, we're very new. If we had a smell, it would be like the plastic of the inside of a new car.

We're working hard on making our simple plugin more powerful. But the first version does what it's already meant to do: install, create and send in no time. Enough said, test drive our baby and let us know what you think:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wysija-newsletters/

Comment: Please make your source code human readable. I look always at the code first in the SVN repo. I would never install such a mess, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

After having tested almost 10 solution free and not so free... i read a tread about newsletter... and BAM! somebody suggest something new... so new that the site is almost empty and the version is not event 1.0... but boy, that is the answer of newslette for wordpress 2012 !... let's just imagine what that program will be in 2 years... it's rocking right now : here is the name : Wysija Version: 0.9.6